# Visual Studio Designer keeps trying to initialize my Collection property

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I've created a UserControl called `CatalogBrowser` which has a property `ListedFamilies` that exposes the currently listed `Family` objects in the control. Here's the code for the property.

```
public List<Family> ListedFamilies {
     get {
         List<Family> returnList = new List<Family>();
         foreach (Object obj in this.familyObjectListView.Objects) {
             returnList.Add((Family)obj);
         }
         return returnList;
     }
     set {
         this.familyObjectListView.ClearObjects();
         this.familyObjectListView.Objects = value;
     }
 }
```

Now in a Form where I am using this control I keep having a problem with Visual Studio adding the following line in the Form's designer file.

```
this.catalogBrowserControl1.ListedFamilies = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<SOMLib.Family>)(resources.GetObject("catalogBrowserControl1.ListedFamilies")));
```

This causes my program to crash because I don't have (or want) a resource in my project to initialize the value of this collection property.

How can I prevent `Visual Studio` from automatically trying to initialize this property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One trick is to add the `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]` attribute to your property.